# Using Dreamweaver as Rails IDE?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dreamweaver

Can I use dreamweaver as an IDE? I can create rails applications on my mac and browse to them and everything, but I just can't view the view files (html.erb) in dreamweaver.

Ideally, I'ld like to be able to just point dreamweaver at the root directory of a rails app, and when I open a view file, it'll be right there in the live view with the embedded ruby compiled into html.

Is this possible?

**I'm not interested in creating rails apps in dreamweaver. Sublime is the job there, but when I give my app a nice look, I really, really like Dreamweaver. I'm also up with just using one stylesheet in my app.**

Or can I sort of make alias links in Dreamweaver? So while I'm not opening the entire rails project in Dreamweaver, I can have the app running in development mode, and I can open it's html.erb pages in Dreamweaver?

I'm running Dreamwaver CC (the latest version)

Comment: Do you know RubyMine ? Made by JetBrains: http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/ I use it and I am very happy with it, take a look ;)

Comment: I don't think Dreamweaver knows how to compile erb code neither run the whole rails server to fetch all the things it needs to generate the views.

Answer (score 0):

I was working with a developer here on a Ruby project and I'm a UX/UI designer and love Dreamweaver. He was able to go in to preferences and set it so Dreamweaver can render the .erb files. I'm not able to see the 'design' side, but can edit the code and get help with auto fill stuff.

Hope that helps.